# Arrange 10 points on five lines where each line(intersecting) has exactly 4 points

Tags: examples-counterexamples, combinatorial-geometry

One possible case is that forming a star and then arranging 10 points on its vertices.

[image]

Is there any other possible case for this arrangement? If not then how can we prove it mathematically?

Degenerated cases like concurrent lines and parallel lines are also allowed.

Comment: Do you allow some degenerate cases: coinciding lines or points, parallel lines, three lines intersecting in one point? Each of the selected points should be a point of an intersection of lines?

Comment: degenerated cases are allowed but now coinciding lines or points

Answer (score 2):

Simply draw your lines in such a way they all intersect in distinct points. This will give rise to $\binom{5}{2}=10$ intersections and since each line intersects the other 4 in distinct locations, each line will have 4 intersections. Place your points on these intersections and you will have your solution.

Since $\binom{5}{2}=10$ is the maximum value for $\binom{5}{k}$ for all $0\le k\le 5$, we know we can't do any better.

EDIT: The key to maximizing these incidences is to share the point with as many lines as possible, thus maximizing the number of incidences per point. Since a system of $n$ lines can intersect in at most $\binom{n}{2}$ points, I can't increase this number of intersections by allowing three or more lines to intersect at a single point. And even if I do allow this, there is a one-for-one trade in intersections versus incidences since the number of points each line contains is fixed.

BTW have you heard of the Szemeredi-Trotter theorem? It isn't very helpful here (the size of the system is too small), but it gives an almost tight asymptotic bound on the number of incidences a system can have.

Comment: This gives rise to OP's solution.  The question is whether there is a different configuration.  Presumably that one would have to have at least one point on three lines.  The question is whether that is possible.

Comment: I was responding to the title, not the text, unfortunately. I noticed that after my original post. I think I have fixed it now.