# Arrange 10 pots in 4 rows such that each contain 4 pots

Tags: combinatorics

How can we arrange 10 pots in 4 rows such that each row cantain 4 pots ?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by “ each row must contain 4 pots”. Given ten pots , all rows cannot simultaneously contain 4 pots.

Comment: It is possible even more: 10 pots in 5 rows each containing 4 pots: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060956/arrange-10-points-on-five-lines-where-each-lineintersecting-has-exactly-4-poin